# Time tracking solution for Windows / Eclipse PHP

Tags: windows, eclipse, scheduling, time-tracking

After seeing this movie and the introduction to Lapsus (http://synapticmishap.co.uk/synapticmishap/lapsuspromo/) I really felt that I had missed this feature in my own daily work.

Are there any time tracking solution for windows that can monitor a set folder and its changes to the content files that may or may not integrate with Eclipse PHP?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You always had time tracking with **[mylyn tasks](http://eclipse.org/mylyn/index.php)** (this is why it is called "Task Timing").

Since Mylyn3.3, you can even:

> Time tracking can now be turned off independently of focusing.
>   Time tracking has always been optional and private since it required task activation and stored all tracking information in the workspace.
>   But it was not previously possible to use focusing without active time being captured.
>   Note that the preference is off by default, since Mylyn makes all activity tracking and automation opt-in.

[image]

[zvikico](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2823/zvikico) mentions in the comments the webminar "**Code at the Speed of Thought with Task-focused Programming**" on that topic: [Watch Webminar](http://www.zend.com/webinar/PHP/70170000000bEjl-webinar-code-at-the-speed-thought-with-task-focused-programming-20100414.flv), and see [presentation slides](http://static.zend.com/topics/Tasktop-Zend-Webinar-s.pdf), from:

- **Mik Kersten**, creator and lead of the Eclipse Mylyn project and CEO of Tasktop Technologies, and
- **Roy Ganor**, Zend Studio and PDT Project Lead.

[alt text http://img203.imageshack.us/img203/121/mylyntasktiming.png](http://img203.imageshack.us/img203/121/mylyntasktiming.png)

Comment: There's a good webinar on the subject (mylyn with PDT) which was given by Zend and Tasktop guys. Look in this page and search for "mylyn": http://www.zend.com/resources/webinars/

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for your help! However, I am looking for something that is a bit more automatic and works in the background without any output. From what I can tell, mylyn needs to be activated every time a task is started?

Answer (score 2):

Check out Chrometa:

http://app.chrometa.com/

It's the nearest thing to Lapsus I can find for Windows machines. Oh, and I'm the developer of Lapsus so thanks for the name drop!

Comment: Hi John! Thanks for your reply - will definitely check it out

Comment: @Glycerine Thanks for the nice words. Hmmm. Don't I know you from somewhere? :)

Comment: hmmm. Dunno - There was the filming of that suggestive blue movie. Were you in that?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on rabbit:
http://code.google.com/p/rabbit-eclipse/

It works basicly also for php develoment.